# Git moving 4 line change of one file to an earlier commit turned into nightmare

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I changed 4 lines in one file and need to apply those changes to an earlier commit. This should be ridiculously easy.

1. I stashed the file
2. Git rebased back to earlier commit
3. Un-stashed file, and then rebase continued

Git reported everything A-OK, checking the commit history reveals git actually created a 3 way merge and duplicated all commits after so now I have 2 sets of commits.

Scratching my head I rebased again and git stopped with a merge conflict, I fixed the merge conflict and now I still have duplicate commits but the 3 way merge was thankfully gone.

So I rebased again to move the duplicates on top of each other and squash them but that ended in merge conflict. I fixed the merge and now I have a 3-way merge all over again - back to square one.

I went through all the steps above once again to get to duplicate commits but no 3-way merge and this time just moved the duplicate commits on top of each other on the rebase and not squash them, I would squash them on 2nd round. However the really strange thing is it eliminated the entire commit containing the 4 line changes and I know I was careful to not erase the line from git rebase todo file.

So since the 4 line changes are now mysteriously gone but thankfully everything else looks fine I decided to rebase back to and edit the commit and re-type out those 4 line changes - Well out of the sheer frustration I forgot to add 2 line changes so only 2 changes got added but to make things even more frustrating It did a bloody 3 way merge again and duplicated once again all commits afterwards.

So as it stands now I'm in rebase hell for a very simple change to one file, 2 lines have been added, 2 forgot to add, and we're back at a 3-way merge making this a nightmare.

Also if it helps any visually here's an ASCII commit tree

```
* 2c935a7 (HEAD -> feature/event-system) Integrated Event System and Fine Tuned Files
* c579fde Finished Event System
| * ec6656e (origin/feature/event-system) Integrated Event System and Fine Tuned Files
| * ee51864 Finished Event System
|/
* 6fcbe87 (origin/develop, develop) Initial Assets and Files Commit
* f5015f8 Initial Libraries Commit
* 77f162a (origin/master, master) Initial Commit
```

**Edit**

To answer some of your questions bettor, heres a much more thorough breakdown of everything

http://pastebin.com/GTzjeVHC

Comment: Could you show the actual commands you ran? And which commit are you trying to change? And is the tree your situation before or after the rebase?

Comment: `git commit -a -s -m "fixup for commit foo bar"; git rebase --interactive foo_bar_hash^`. This might not work if `foo_bar_hash` is an initial commit. In that case you need to add `--root`.

Comment: Also useful would be if you can include what the 4 line change was, and what kind of conflicts you were getting. Without that info and the answers to @Schwern's questions, this post is pretty unclear.

Comment: What rebase command did you use to go back to the earlier commit ?

Comment: And were there any merge conflicts ?

Comment: Sorry for late response I had gotten a bit busy, give me a quick second to bring up and prepare the walk-through which will answer all the questions. Sorry my earlier answer was vague.

Comment: Edited the question with link to more full breakdown

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was no 3-way merge from the beginning and nothing I was doing was wrong.

`git log` was pointing out to me visually the remote history mixed in with my history which when lumped together looked like my history was really messed up and made me scared to push.

But taking a leap of faith and pushing anyways updated the remote-end and `git log` now shows the same thing with no history divergence. I future note to anyone who may be confused as had it been written anywhere would have saved me many hours of trying to figure things out.